# Linear Transformation Similarity - Answer verifications

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $B = \{1,x,x^2\}$ and $B^\prime = \{1, 1+ x, 1+ x + x^2\}$ and $T(p(x)) = p(x) - x\frac{dp}{dx}$.
>
> 1. Find $[T]_B$
> 2. Find the transition matrix from $B^\prime$ to $B$.
> 3. Find the transition matrix from $B$ to $B^\prime$.
> 4. Find $[T]_{B^\prime}$ and simplify

**My attempt**

1. $[T]_B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$
2. $P = P_{B^\prime \to B} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$
3. $P^{-1} = P_{B \to B^\prime} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 &0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$
4. $[T]_{B^\prime} = P^{-1}[T]_BP = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 &1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Is this correct?

Comment: What does *simplify* mean?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli - they do not specify, so I simply assumed row reduction to leave it in it's "simplest" form?

Comment: Methodologically, all the passages are correct. And it seems the calculations are too. On that point, are you familiar with [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I am familiar with wolframalpha :). I just did not know you can do this on there :)

Comment: The syntaxis should be something like " {{a,b},{c,d}} " for
$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$, " inv(A) " for $A^{-1}$, and " A.B " for $A\cdot B$.